# Subtract 12 hours from timestamp (batch file)

Tags: powershell, batch

So I have a bunch of video files from 3 cameras and while 2 cameras have the times sync'ed together, one camera was off by 12 hours (so the other two are correct starting at 5/26 12:00pm, the other one started at 5/27 12:00am).

Is there a utility or a way to subtract 12 hours from the MODIFIED date from the command line? I'd assume it'd need to be some kind of batch script or perhaps powershell?

Help?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these PowerShell script:

```
$path = "C:\path\to\your\folder"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
ForEach-Object{
  $_.LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime.AddHours(-12)
}
```

Change `$path` to your folder path. You can add `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem` if you need to do it for subfolders too.

Comment: That will change the last modified time for all files not just the broken ones.